# AngulaJS ng-options initially selected value from an

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an object with property: value structure with should be used for the ng-options to create the select dropdown. I also have a ng-model variable which contains the property which should be currently selected. The problem is that I can't figure out how to fix the initial selection.
You can find the code here

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="id as value for (id, value) in cars track by id">
```

http://jsbin.com/wukanenozu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use "track by"

> Do not use  as and track by in the same expression. They are not
>   designed to work together.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="id as value for (id, value) in cars ">
</select>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        frd : "Ford",
        ft1 : "Fiat",
        vlv : "Volvo"
    }
    $scope.selectedCar = 'ft1';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="id as value for (id, value) in cars ">
</select>
<h1>You selected model: {{selectedCar}}</h1>

</div>

<p>This example demonstrates the use of an object as the data source when creating a dropdown list.</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what should look like the ng-options if the cars are stored in array like
`[{key: 'frd', value: 'Ford'},
{key:'ft1', value:'Fiat'},
{key:'vlv', value:'Volvo'}]`